# How to secure reactor netServer with spring security?

Tags: spring-security, netty, spring-boot, reactor

I try to develop an "hybrid" server using spring boot webApplication with embedded tomcat and a netServer from reactor to scale-up my Rest Api.
There are no Spring controller, all the incoming request are handled by the netServer.
Never the less i'd like to have a login page using spring security remember me facilities to authenticate the user and use this authentication to secure incoming request on the reactor netServer.

I start to implements the netServer, according to this tutorial [reactor thumbmailer](https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactor-thumbnailer/)

here is my netServer :

```
NetServer<FullHttpRequest, FullHttpResponse> server = new TcpServerSpec<FullHttpRequest, FullHttpResponse>(NettyTcpServer.class)
        .env(env)
        .dispatcher("sync")
        .listen(8080)
        .options(opts)
        .consume(ch -> {
          // attach an error handler
          ch.when(Throwable.class, UserController.errorHandler(ch));

          // filter requests by URI
          Stream<FullHttpRequest> in = ch.in();

          // serve image thumbnail to browser
          in.filter((FullHttpRequest req) -> req.getUri().startsWith(UserController.GET_USER_PROFILE))
            .consume(UserController.getUserProfile(ch));

        })
        .get();
```

So when a user try to load his profile, the incoming request is handled by the userController :

```
public static Consumer<FullHttpRequest> getUserProfile(NetChannel<FullHttpRequest, FullHttpResponse> channel) {

    UserService userService = StaticContextAccessor.getBean(UserService.class);

    return req -> {
        try {
            LoginDTO login = RestApiUtils.parseJson(LoginDTO.class, RestApiUtils.getJsonContent(req));


            DefaultFullHttpResponse resp = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, OK);

            String result = userService.loadUserProfile(login);
            resp.headers().set(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
            resp.headers().set(CONTENT_LENGTH, result.length());
            resp.content().writeBytes(result.getBytes());
            channel.send(resp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            channel.send(badRequest(e.getMessage()));
        }
    };

}
```

Here is the hack : getUserProfile is a static methode, so i can't use GlobalMethodSecurity to secure it. 
i then inject a userService in this controller using a StaticContextAccessor :

```
@Component
public class StaticContextAccessor {

  private static StaticContextAccessor instance;

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @PostConstruct
  public void registerInstance() {
      instance = this;
  }

  public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> clazz) {
      return instance.applicationContext.getBean(clazz);
  }

}
```

UserService :

```
@Service
@PreAuthorize("true")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

  public String loadUserProfile(LoginDTO login){

    //TODO load profile in mongo

    return new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(login);
  }

}
```

the service is managed by spring so i guess i could use spring GlobalMethodSecurity on it (i m still developping this part, but i'm not sure this is the best way to secure my netServer)

Is there a easier way to use Spring security on reactor netServer ???
My first web site version was developped with nodeJS to handle many concurent users, and i try to refactor it using a JVM nio solution.
So is spring / reactor / netty a good solution to have a highly scalable server, or should i use something like play! or vertx.io ?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried bootstrapping your `NetServer` from within a JavaConfig `@Bean` method? Something like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactor
class AppConfig {

  public Function<NetChannel, UserController> users() {
    return new UserControllerFactory();
  }

  @Bean
  public NetServer netServer(Environment env, Function<NetChannel, UserController> users) {
    return new TcpServerSpec(NettyTcpServer.class)
      .env(env)
      .dispatcher("sync")
      .listen(8080)
      .options(opts)
      .consume(ch -> {
        // attach an error handler
        ch.when(Throwable.class, UserController.errorHandler(ch));

        // filter requests by URI
        Stream<FullHttpRequest> in = ch.in();

        // serve image thumbnail to browser
        in.filter((FullHttpRequest req) -> req.getUri().startsWith(UserController.GET_USER_PROFILE))
          .consume(users.apply(ch));
      })
      .get();
  }

}
```

This should preserve your Spring Security support and enable you to share handlers as beans rather than as return values from static methods. In general, just about everything you need to do in a Reactor TCP app can be done using beans and injection and by returing the `NetServer` as a bean itself.